# Figuring out syntax for Grand Central Dispatch in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have the following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

    // Do stuff in the backgroud

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        // Do stuff on the UI thread

    }
}
```

However it will not compile.  The inner call to dispatch_async returns the following compile error:

```
Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '(dispatch_queue_t!, () -> () -> $T3)'
```

I can't seem to figure out how to write this so that it works like I used to be able to in Objective C. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: I can't say with completely certainty without knowing what's inside your closure, but you're probably running in to [Implicit Returns from Single-Expression Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_157). Try putting an explicit `return` at the end of your inner closure.

Comment: Mike S, this seems to have worked. Thanks!  If you post this as an answer, I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Closures in Swift can have implicit returns if they only contain a single expression (see: [Implicit Returns from Single-Expression Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_157)). Your inner closure most likely has a single expression in it to update the UI. The compiler is using the result of that expression as the return value for the closure which makes the closure's signature not match the signature `dispatch_async` wants. Since `dispatch_async` wants a closure that returns `()` (or `Void`), the fix is to just add an explicit `return` at the end of your closure:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

    // Do stuff in the backgroud

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        // Do stuff on the UI thread

        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Contents of inner closure are: self.targetSprite?.texture = SKTexture(image: self.mainImage);  ...  so this answer is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced the closing paranthesis and the braces:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    // Do stuff in the background

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // Do stuff on the UI thread
    })
})
```

Comment: No, since the closure is the last parameter, it can be a trailing closure. This is not the problem.

Comment: yes, I didn't say it wouldn't. What I'm saying is his code works just fine too.

Comment: well, obviously he's got some issue, but if you copy/paste exactly what he has in the question, it compiles just fine. Your code and his are equivalent.